# How can i use strings and text in program launch arguments in c#

Tags: java, c#

I want to code a NDS VC Injector as PC tool for the WiiU (this was the uninteresting part where i don't need much help)
I need help with launching a program with a text and a string in the argument.
when i launch it in batch it looks like this "java -jar JNUSTool.jar %TID% %TK% -file .*"
how can i replicate this in c# ?

Comment: `yourexe.exe %TID% %TK% -file .*`? What have you tried doing and how does it not work? Share your code (a [mcve]) and explain the issues (including error messages, etc.)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nKux6PHw code
https://pastebin.com/nH7eSxt6 error

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add your code.

Comment: `C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_24\\binjava.exe` - can't be right. It'd need to at least be `C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_24\\bin\\java.exe`. And the error message tells you that it can't find the file, so it's your job to make sure all the paths are correct

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/

The comand line arguments show up as an array of string.

```
class TestClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Display the number of command line arguments:
        System.Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
    }
}
```